# Null pointer when auto-wiring in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, coding-style

Looking for what the standard is for auto-wiring an external sdk class I am trying this way but getting a null pointer.. I am using AmazonDynamoDBClient in a spring boot project. So I think I have my config class that is like this

```
@Configuration
public class DynamoDBClientBuilder {

    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDBClient;
    @Bean
    public void DynamoDBClientBuilderInitializer() {

        amazonDynamoDBClient = this.initiateClient();

    }

    private AmazonDynamoDB initiateClient() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4569", "us-west-1"))
                    .build();
    }
}
```

Then I have the class where I want to use that client in the spring project, is it best to do something like this outside of any methods

```
    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBClientBuilder db;
    private AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDBClient = null;
```

And then this in either the constructor or where we want to use the client

```
amazonDynamoDBClient = db.amazonDynamoDBClient;
```

I'm not really sure why i am getting a null pointer it seems the config class isn't getting initiated before the class that wants to use it. Also would be interest to hear what the best practice is or is there a nicer way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Best practice for all autowiring is to use constructor injection instead of field injection. Whether to inject the builder or a built client will depend on your specific needs, such as being able to customize it per service or handle lifecycle operations. Note that Spring Cloud AWS can handle a lot of this auto-config for you, although it has _very_ strong opinions and isn't for everyone.

Comment: Actually the above gives me a null pointer exception on amazonDynamoDBClient = db.amazonDynamoDBClient;, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, use constructor injection as I recommended. `@Autowired` fields aren't injected until after the object is created, which is much of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
public class DynamoDBClientBuilder {
    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4569", "us-west-1"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

And then inject your bean like this:

```
@Autowired
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;
```

or with constructor (recommended):

```
private final AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;

@Autowired
public MyClass(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB) {
        this.amazonDynamoDB = amazonDynamoDB;
    }
```

And notice that your config calss must be covered with component scan to be able to create bean in spring context

Comment: That worker perfectly! I am going to accept answer but just wondering first could you explain what is happening or tell me if I am correct in my understanding which is...

Spring will call the configuration classes first and create the AmazonDynamoDb instance, does this mean then because of the method name there we can reference it as a parameter amazonDynamoDB anywhere in the application that is annotated with autowired?

Comment: @AnonymousAlias Yep, spring creates bean whitch you can inject by specifying an anttribute name. By the way, you can mark the injection with @Qualifier annotation to inject a specific bean into parameter. e.g. you have declared another bean with method  `amazonDynamoDB2()`, so u can inject it by typing Autowired parameter as: 
`@Autowired AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB2;`
or:
`@Autowired @Qualifier("amazonDynamoDB2") AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;`

Comment: As for constructor parameter, it will be like that:`@Qualifier("amazonDynamoDB2") AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB`